# How to use loop to do addition of specific rows

Tags: sum, multiple-columns

I need to do the addition of scores from a test, which are found across 20 rows (A1-A20 are the labels of the rows) but there are 400 participants (400 columns).

How would I use a loop function in R to do the sum of data from A1-A20 for all the 400 columns and just form a single column containing the sum of the data?

Comment: By the way, I see that you are pretty new here. Welcome to Stack Overflow :D Next time you post a question, please provide a little more background information about what you are trying to do. In this case, you need to specify what programming language you are using. Depending on the tool, you might not need a for loop at all in the first place. For example, you don't do a for loop in MySQL or Excel sheet.

Comment: I edited it to make it clearer, would you be able to help at all?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an experience in R, but it seems that the basic idea is the same. Maybe the tutorial on this link can help. https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/for-loop/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to add all of the 400 columns' data, you'll probably need to use a loop, assuming that you are using a programming language that is equipped with for loop, such as C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript etc.

It will look like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 400; i++){
    // Do the addition. It will be iterated 400 times in this example
}
```

One of practical examples that I can come up with is maybe when you want to calculate the average of the score of students. When there are 400 students and you want to figure out the average score, you add up all of the 400 students' scores and divide the sum by 400. In this kind of situation, for loop comes in handy.

Here is an example using Java.

```
// we are just assuming that there is an array list of int type named studentScores, where 400 students' socores are stored. 
float average = 0; 
int sum = 0; 
int noOfStudents = studentScores.size();

for(int i = 0; i < noOfStudents; i++){
    sum = sum + studentScores[i];
}

average = (float)sum / noOfStudents; 
System.out.println("The average score is " + average);
```